# Ошибка при вызове клавиатуры что делать aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

У меня есть хандлер, он вызывается после нажатии на инлайн кнопку. В нем должно будет редактироваться сообщение, но.. Это я сделаю сам, я столкнулся с проблемой.. Я в этом хандлере сделал на время вызов нового сообщения:

```
await call.message.answer('text', reply_markup=name_keyboard)
```

И прикол в том что мне выходит ошибка клавиатуры:

```
Can't parse reply keyboard markup json object
```

Что мне делать? Если я не ввожу клавиатуру сюда, то сообщение отправляется.

Создал я клаву вот так:

```
name_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlinekeyboardButton('text button', callback_data='text')
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что мои клавиатуры начинаются в next
Убрав из название слово next все заработало)